# Zeppelin spark jobs are getting stuck and not terminating on it own

Tags: scala, apache-spark, interpreter, apache-zeppelin

Whenever I run spark jobs from zeppelin it gets stuck and keeps running till 2.5-3 hours then after that I get an error mentioned below for hung spark job.

> java.lang.NullPointerException    at
> org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:170)    at
> org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.ClientFactory.create(ClientFactory.java:51)
> at
> org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.ClientFactory.create(ClientFactory.java:37)
> at
> org.apache.commons.pool2.BasePooledObjectFactory.makeObject(BasePooledObjectFactory.java:60)
> at
> org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.create(GenericObjectPool.java:861)

I am also facing an error that some spark jobs keep running and I need to kill the session from hue and run sc.stop() to stop the spark context and then I need to restart the spark interpreter to carry on running the jobs.

I am facing this issue only in spark jobs and they are continuously getting stuck and never completes.

Dspark.executor.memory=8g -Dspark.cores.max=16"
Above mentioned are the spark configs in zeppelin.

What can I do to get rid off the spark jobs getting hung and zeppelin session not terminating on it's own gracefully, everytime I need to kill the session and restart the spark interpreter.

PFB my spark interpreter configs----->

```
SPARK_HOME                                         /lib/spark2/
args    
master                                             yarn-client
spark.app.name                                     Zeppelin
spark.cores.max 
spark.executor.memory   
spark.yarn.keytab   
spark.yarn.principal    
zeppelin.R.cmd                                     R
zeppelin.R.image.width                             100%
zeppelin.R.knitr                                   true
zeppelin.R.render.options                      out.format = 'html', comment = NA, 
                         echo = FALSE, results = 'asis', message = F, warning = F
zeppelin.dep.additionalRemoteRepository            spark-packages, 
                                http://dl.bintray.com/spark-packages/maven,false;
zeppelin.dep.localrepo                             local-repo
zeppelin.interpreter.localRepo                     loc_of_local_repo
zeppelin.interpreter.output.limit                  102400
zeppelin.pyspark.python                            python
zeppelin.pyspark.useIPython                        true
zeppelin.spark.concurrentSQL                       false
zeppelin.spark.enableSupportedVersionCheck         true
zeppelin.spark.importImplicit                      true
zeppelin.spark.keytab                              loc_of_keytab
zeppelin.spark.maxResult                           1000
zeppelin.spark.principal                           kerberos zeppelinl@realm
zeppelin.spark.printREPLOutput                     true
zeppelin.spark.sql.interpolation                   false
zeppelin.spark.sql.stacktrace                      false
zeppelin.spark.ui.hidden                           false
zeppelin.spark.uiWebUrl 
zeppelin.spark.useHiveContext                      true
zeppelin.spark.useNew                              true
```

Comment: Are you spark jobs running fine when you run them without zeppelin?

Comment: Hi Cronoik,
Yes, spark jobs are running fine without zeppelin.

Comment: Does this error occure even for simple jobs (like `spark.sql('SOME STATEMENT').show()`)?

Comment: Hi Cronoik,
Yes, for every spark job. Even for simple spark job like sc.version of print(sc.sparkUser).

In other cluster my spark jobs run and keeps on running forever until and unless I either restart my spark interpreter or kill the session from Hue.

Comment: Maybe your settings aren't correct. Have you correctly set the [spark master](http://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.8.0/interpreter/spark.html)?

Comment: Yes, my spark master in zeppelin is yarn-client. Should I share the interpreter configs?

Comment: I've added my spark interpreter properties in the question posted above.